# Change the color of cancel button in UIAlertController with preferredStyle: .ActionSheet

Tags: swift, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to change the color of cancel button to red , i know we can by using Destructive style

```
  let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Destructive) { action -> Void in
            print("Cancel")
        }
```

but i want the cancel button separately , like this [image]

Comment: @Miteshjadav the question was about cancel button. `tintColor` vice versa changes other buttons color. Reported

Answer (score 26):

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) 
cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Comment: How safe is this solution? What if apple decides to change the key name in future updates of iOS?

Comment: I used this solution in apps, successfully approved on iTunes.

Comment: How can I use custom font in cancel button?

Answer (score 6):

This is code of how to make the alert like you said:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Hello World", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open in Google Maps", style: . default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open in Google", style: . default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy Address", style: . default, handler: nil))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
```

You have to use 2 kind of style.
In here, I used `.destructive` and `.default`, It will separate alert action into 2 part

Comment: .destructive does not makes the cancel button separate as @bikram sapkota wants even if we use .default with rest actions.

Comment: @NishadArora above comment is correct. .destructive does not makes the cancel button separate

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

You can change the `color` of the **alert action** button using the below code.

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: then how to change the background colour for cancel button

Comment: how to change the background colour of the cancel button?

Answer (score 2):

Just give the style property of the button as destructive.

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift4.2**

If you have multiple `UIAlertAction`, then add "Cancel" `UIAlertAction` in `UIAlertController` like that.

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Your Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "first",style: .default, handler: { action in
     //Do something....           
   }))
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "second", style: .default, handler: { action in
     //Do something....           
   }))
// Add cancel UIAlertAction
 let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
     cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
     alert.addAction(cancelAction).  
     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: how to change the background colour of the cancel button?

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to achieve the same output for the cancel button and also don't want to change the cancel button type to destructive. I have used cancel type for the cancel button in the code. To achieve the same, You can use the following code:-**

```
 //MARK:- Function to create the action sheet

  func showAlertSheet(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // Create Google Map button
    let googleMap = UIAlertAction(title: "Open in Google Maps", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");

    }
    alertController.addAction(googleMap)

    // Create Map button
    let map = UIAlertAction(title: "Open in Maps", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");

    }
    alertController.addAction(map)

     // Create copy Address button
    let copyAddress = UIAlertAction(title: "Copy Address", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");

    }
    alertController.addAction(copyAddress)

    // Create Cancel button
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Cancel button tapped");
    }
    // Change Cancel title color according to your requirements
    cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present Dialog message
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

**And also you have the option to change the cancel button text color. The output of the code is like this:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the style from `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` to `UIAlertActionStyleDestructive` in objective C:

```
UIAlertAction* button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button title here"
                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                      {
                                          // Handle action here....
                                      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alert.view.tintColor` which will be applied for `.cancel` and `.default` styles